# How do I notify a message posted from the application?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

When my application publishes a message on the user's wall  (through permits streampublish) I want you to get a notification to the user in red. How can I do?

If I can not there are alternative solutions? . For example, I thought to send a private message to you through my application. how can I do?

Comment: What is the table the structure you are saving the posts in ?

Comment: @UserB Why you  want know the structure the table ? I want know how send notification at user after that the application have public message on wall users' or I want know how send a private message to user

Answer (score 0):

Showing Notifications

You can do this by using a db column that holds the notification status lets say when the notification_status = 0 the user didn't see the notification yet

when the notification_status = 1 
then you send request to server every mount of time lets say 15 seconds and then test weather there is notification_status = 0 or not if yes show a div and send the number of notifications in it

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.post("notifications_tester.php",function(data){
    if(data  != 0 )
    {
         $('#notifications_div').show().html(data);
    }
    else
   {
         $('#notifications_div').hide().html("");
   }
});
}, 15000);
```

sample what would be in notifications_test.php

```
session_start(); 
//connect to the DB 

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."' AND notification_status = 0");
echo mysql_num_rows($q);
```

Comment: I have not given to understand. Let me explain. When my application writes a post on their wall I wish the user a notification is displayed on his facebook profile. This behavior is by default when a user leaves a message on the wall of another user. Why not do the same when it is the application to leave a message on their wall?